# Linux: how to get the list of libraries and their memory details from a running binary?

Tags: linux

While running a binary on linux62, the binary took heavy amount of memory. 
This particularly happening after it loads java. The same thing is running fine with less memory on earlier versions of Linux.

So i want to know, is there any tools that can list the loaded libraries and their memory size, of a running binary. 
I didn't get any utilities to do this, on a binary that is currently running. 
ldd and objdump are taken the details only from the object, not from the process that is running.

Since the java library is loaded only after my program is up and running(loading java is optional), i need a tool to list out the set of libraries with their memory details from the running binary. So that i can understand which library takes more memory and i can debug further.

Thanks
Thanga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# pidof init
1
# cat /proc/1/maps
00400000-004d2000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 9790                               /bin/systemd
006d2000-006df000 r--p 000d2000 fd:02 9790                               /bin/systemd
006df000-006e0000 rw-p 000df000 fd:02 9790                               /bin/systemd
006e0000-006e1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
008df000-008e2000 rw-p 000df000 fd:02 9790                               /bin/systemd
0203d000-036b1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
3c0c200000-3c0c222000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 11536                          /lib64/ld-2.14.90.so
3c0c421000-3c0c422000 r--p 00021000 fd:02 11536                          /lib64/ld-2.14.90.so
3c0c422000-3c0c423000 rw-p 00022000 fd:02 11536                          /lib64/ld-2.14.90.so
3c0c423000-3c0c424000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3c0c600000-3c0c7ad000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 12080                          /lib64/libc-2.14.90.so
3c0c7ad000-3c0c9ad000 ---p 001ad000 fd:02 12080                          /lib64/libc-2.14.90.so
3c0c9ad000-3c0c9b1000 r--p 001ad000 fd:02 12080                          /lib64/libc-2.14.90.so
3c0c9b1000-3c0c9b3000 rw-p 001b1000 fd:02 12080                          /lib64/libc-2.14.90.so
3c0c9b3000-3c0c9b8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3c0ce00000-3c0ce02000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 10569                          /lib64/libdl-2.14.90.so
3c0ce02000-3c0d002000 ---p 00002000 fd:02 10569                          /lib64/libdl-2.14.90.so
3c0d002000-3c0d003000 r--p 00002000 fd:02 10569                          /lib64/libdl-2.14.90.so
3c0d003000-3c0d004000 rw-p 00003000 fd:02 10569                          /lib64/libdl-2.14.90.so
3c0d200000-3c0d217000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 6336                           /lib64/libpthread-2.14.90.so
3c0d217000-3c0d416000 ---p 00017000 fd:02 6336                           /lib64/libpthread-2.14.90.so
3c0d416000-3c0d417000 r--p 00016000 fd:02 6336                           /lib64/libpthread-2.14.90.so
3c0d417000-3c0d418000 rw-p 00017000 fd:02 6336                           /lib64/libpthread-2.14.90.so
3c0d418000-3c0d41c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3c0da00000-3c0da07000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 22071                          /lib64/librt-2.14.90.so
3c0da07000-3c0dc06000 ---p 00007000 fd:02 22071                          /lib64/librt-2.14.90.so
3c0dc06000-3c0dc07000 r--p 00006000 fd:02 22071                          /lib64/librt-2.14.90.so
3c0dc07000-3c0dc08000 rw-p 00007000 fd:02 22071                          /lib64/librt-2.14.90.so
3c0de00000-3c0de15000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 16692                          /lib64/libgcc_s-4.6.3-20120306.so.1
3c0de15000-3c0e014000 ---p 00015000 fd:02 16692                          /lib64/libgcc_s-4.6.3-20120306.so.1
3c0e014000-3c0e015000 rw-p 00014000 fd:02 16692                          /lib64/libgcc_s-4.6.3-20120306.so.1
3c0e200000-3c0e21d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 28104                          /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3c0e21d000-3c0e41d000 ---p 0001d000 fd:02 28104                          /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3c0e41d000-3c0e41e000 r--p 0001d000 fd:02 28104                          /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3c0e41e000-3c0e41f000 rw-p 0001e000 fd:02 28104                          /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3c0e41f000-3c0e420000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3c0ee00000-3c0ee04000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 63328                          /lib64/libcap.so.2.22
3c0ee04000-3c0f003000 ---p 00004000 fd:02 63328                          /lib64/libcap.so.2.22
3c0f003000-3c0f004000 rw-p 00003000 fd:02 63328                          /lib64/libcap.so.2.22
3c12600000-3c12643000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 52994                          /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3.5.6
3c12643000-3c12842000 ---p 00043000 fd:02 52994                          /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3.5.6
3c12842000-3c12843000 r--p 00042000 fd:02 52994                          /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3.5.6
3c12843000-3c12844000 rw-p 00043000 fd:02 52994                          /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3.5.6
3c1be00000-3c1be17000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 57102                          /lib64/libaudit.so.1.0.0
3c1be17000-3c1c017000 ---p 00017000 fd:02 57102                          /lib64/libaudit.so.1.0.0
3c1c017000-3c1c018000 r--p 00017000 fd:02 57102                          /lib64/libaudit.so.1.0.0
3c1c018000-3c1c019000 rw-p 00018000 fd:02 57102                          /lib64/libaudit.so.1.0.0
3c1c019000-3c1c01d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3c1c600000-3c1c604000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 13766                          /lib64/libattr.so.1.1.0
3c1c604000-3c1c803000 ---p 00004000 fd:02 13766                          /lib64/libattr.so.1.1.0
3c1c803000-3c1c804000 rw-p 00003000 fd:02 13766                          /lib64/libattr.so.1.1.0
3c1d200000-3c1d20d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 76182                          /lib64/libpam.so.0.83.1
3c1d20d000-3c1d40c000 ---p 0000d000 fd:02 76182                          /lib64/libpam.so.0.83.1
3c1d40c000-3c1d40d000 r--p 0000c000 fd:02 76182                          /lib64/libpam.so.0.83.1
3c1d40d000-3c1d40e000 rw-p 0000d000 fd:02 76182                          /lib64/libpam.so.0.83.1
3c1d600000-3c1d617000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 18152                          /lib64/libnsl-2.14.90.so
3c1d617000-3c1d816000 ---p 00017000 fd:02 18152                          /lib64/libnsl-2.14.90.so
3c1d816000-3c1d817000 r--p 00016000 fd:02 18152                          /lib64/libnsl-2.14.90.so
3c1d817000-3c1d818000 rw-p 00017000 fd:02 18152                          /lib64/libnsl-2.14.90.so
3c1d818000-3c1d81a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3c1ea00000-3c1ea0e000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 14124                          /lib64/libudev.so.0.12.0
3c1ea0e000-3c1ec0e000 ---p 0000e000 fd:02 14124                          /lib64/libudev.so.0.12.0
3c1ec0e000-3c1ec0f000 r--p 0000e000 fd:02 14124                          /lib64/libudev.so.0.12.0
3c1ec0f000-3c1ec10000 rw-p 0000f000 fd:02 14124                          /lib64/libudev.so.0.12.0
3c27000000-3c27008000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 76173                          /lib64/libwrap.so.0.7.6
3c27008000-3c27208000 ---p 00008000 fd:02 76173                          /lib64/libwrap.so.0.7.6
3c27208000-3c27209000 rw-p 00008000 fd:02 76173                          /lib64/libwrap.so.0.7.6
3c27209000-3c2720a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7febd3c96000-7febd3ca2000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 45355                      /lib64/libnss_files-2.14.90.so
7febd3ca2000-7febd3ea1000 ---p 0000c000 fd:02 45355                      /lib64/libnss_files-2.14.90.so
7febd3ea1000-7febd3ea2000 r--p 0000b000 fd:02 45355                      /lib64/libnss_files-2.14.90.so
7febd3ea2000-7febd3ea3000 rw-p 0000c000 fd:02 45355                      /lib64/libnss_files-2.14.90.so
7febd3ea3000-7febd403c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7febd40ca000-7febd40d2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7febd40f9000-7febd40fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffce1cd000-7fffce1ee000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffce1ff000-7fffce200000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```